# Tkinter GUI is not updating with input after 1st iteration

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, nlp

So, I made a Tkinter GUI for a NLP Multi-Class Classification. I have a text input in text box and it will show me the output as well as a radar chart. It is working fine for the 1st iteration. But it is not running again and providing output for the next input. I referred to some examples, but couldn't find what is wrong with the code

Also I made this in a Jupyter-Lab. I am getting the output for 2nd input in the cell output

Here is my code:

```py
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Root Cause Analyser')
root.geometry('600x500')

head = Label(root, text='Root Cause Error Finder',font=('helvetica', 14 , 'bold'))
head.pack()
e = Entry(root, width=1000,borderwidth=6, font=('helvetica',15,),border=7)
e.pack()

b = Button(root, text = 'Check', font=('helvetica', 20 , 'bold'), fg = 'white', bg = 'green', command = func)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The Function `func()` is

```py
def func():
    
    text = e.get()

    # creating a list of labels
    lab1 = ['Machine','Man','Method']

    # cleaning the text
    # text = clean_text(text)
    # text = preprocess_text(text)

    # predict the text
    text=[text]
    p = pipeline_log.predict_proba(text)
    k = p.tolist()
    k= k[0]
    
    #res = {lab1[i]: k[i] for i in range(len(lab1))}
    res ={'Label':lab1,'Probability':k}
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(res)

    print(p)

    # convert the words in string with the help of list
    # s = [str(i) for i in p]
    # a = int("".join(s))
    a = pipeline_log.predict(text)
    # show out the final result
    res = str("Root Cause Could be : " + a)

    if a=='Man':

        classification = Label(root, text=res, font=('helvetica', 15 , 'bold'), fg="red")
        classification.pack()
    elif a=='Machine':

        classification = Label(root, text=res, font=('helvetica', 15 , 'bold'), fg="blue")
        classification.pack()
    elif a=='Method':

        classification = Label(root, text=res, font=('helvetica', 15 , 'bold'), fg="orange")
        classification.pack()

    # Making a Radar Chart
    angles=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,len(lab1), endpoint=False)
    angles=np.concatenate((angles,[angles[0]])) 
    lab1.append(lab1[0])
    k.append(k[0])
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
    ax=fig.add_subplot(polar=True)
    chart_type = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
    chart_type.get_tk_widget().pack()
    ax.plot(angles,k)
    #fill plot
    ax.fill(angles, k, alpha=0.25, color='g')
    # Add labels
    ax.set_thetagrids(angles * 180/np.pi, lab1)
    # plt.show()
```

So when I run the code and enter the text and click on the 'Check' Button I get this output which is desirable [1st time run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaQN5.png), but then when I enter the new text it shows [2nd text run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7TOA.png).

When I close the GUI I also print the output probabilities on which the output is determined as shown in the `func()`. Here is the a snippet of the [Probability list of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBUsq.png)

When I close the GUI and Again run it with the same text, it shows the desirable output as here [new run on the same text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lURbp.png)

I want the GUI to show the output for the next text I enter i.e. I want to have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lURbp.png) after [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaQN5.png) without running the code again.

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre] in order to identify the issue.  Also how do you know that the function does not work in second iteration?

Comment: @acw1668 Umm that's why I mentioned that the function output is showing the cell results after the 1st output in Jupyter cell. I will put the images to the GUI as well as the Jupyter code.

Comment: You need to remove the previous result.  The second result is put outside the viewable area of the window.

Comment: the function has a multitude of undefined variables. so it is not possible to reproduce the error... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to this `tk.` to every widgets.

Comment: line 16, in func
    text = clean_text(text)
           ^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'clean_text' is not defined

Comment: Create only one ```Figure``` and ```FigureCanvasTkAgg``` and reuse them.